# how do code a sql statement replacing all x'BF' with x'00' for a certain data field that contains the ascii downside ? to replace it with null x'00'

Tags: oracle11g

how do I code this properly to work in Oracle SQL :

update table_name
set field_name = 
 replace(field_name, x'BF', x'00') 
where condition expression ;

Not sure how to code the replace all occurrence of hex 'BF' with null value hex'00' contained in data field field_name.

Comment: I don't think you really want to replace them with a null character, that will just cause you more problems later when other things try to use the strings. You may want to just remove them completely - if you're sure the original character isn't recoverable. I'd be more worried about how the data got in there.

Comment: I believe user was doing a cut/paste of certain text which resulted in getting the character downside ?  and wanted to replace this with hex '00'

Comment: it is similar to say, replacing a alt-tab character with spaces, for this matter, they want 00

Comment: As long as it wasn't an accented character, or smart quote, or something - that was legitimate but lost through character set mismatches/conversions. I still think replacing it with a null character isn't a good idea, but it's your data *8-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [the `unistr()` function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/UNISTR.html) to provide a Unicode character. e.g.:

```
update table_name
set field_name = replace(field_name, unistr('\00bf'))
where condition expression ;
```

which would remove the `¿` character completely; or to replace it with a null character:

```
set field_name = replace(field_name, unistr('\00bf'), unistr('\0000'))
```

though I suspect sticking a null in there will confuse things even more later, when some other system tries to read that text and stops at the null.

Quick demo:

```
with t (str) as (
  select 'A ¿ char' from dual
)
select str,
  replace(str, unistr('\00bf')) as removed,
  replace(str, unistr('\00bf'), unistr('\0000')) as replaced,
  dump(replace(str, unistr('\00bf')), 16) as removed_hex,
  dump(replace(str, unistr('\00bf'), unistr('\0000')), 16) as replaced_hex
from t;

STR       REMOVED   REPLACED  REMOVED_HEX                         REPLACED_HEX
--------- --------- --------- ----------------------------------- -----------------------------------
A ¿ char  A  char   A   char  Typ=1 Len=7: 41,20,20,63,68,61,72   Typ=1 Len=8: 41,20,0,20,63,68,61,72
```

(Just as an example of the problems you'll have - because of the null I couldn't copy and paste that from SQL Developer, and had to switch to SQL*Plus...)

The first dump shows the two spaces (hex 20) next to each other; the second shows a null character between them.